# In Dune, was there any danger from Feyd-Rautha's poison needle?

Tags: dune

In Paul's duel with Feyd-Rautha, he is worried when Feyd-Rautha attempts to cheat with a hidden poison needle. But isn't Paul immune to poison? Furthermore, why didn't the snoopers detect the poison?

Comment: he most likely would have been immune to dieing from the poison though it may have been slowed down considerably by it for a brief period.

Comment: If it slowed him down in combat - he dies by a blade.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The snoopers seem to have missed the poison on the blade because it wasn't *deadly* (the snoopers are evidently only looking for **fatal** poisons):

> He realigned his own metabolism to match this threat and change the
>   molecules of the soporific, but he felt a thrill of doubt. They’d been
>   prepared with soporific on a blade. **A soporific. Nothing to alert a
>   poison snooper,** but strong enough to slow the muscles it touched. His
>   enemies had their own plans within plans, their own stacked
>   treacheries.

He's then worried about the dart, not because the poison might *kill* him but because if they've already used one novel poison against him (albeit ineffectively), the next one may have more of an effect.

Set against the backdrop of a knife fight where every split-second counts, you can see why he'd want to avoid being drugged even if he's reasonably confident of being able to overcome its effects:

> “You see it there on my hip?” Feyd-Rautha whispered. “Your death,
>   fool.” And he began twisting himself around, forcing the poisoned
>   needle closer and closer. **“It’ll stop your muscles and my knife will
>   finish you.** There’ll be never a trace left to detect!”

Comment: "I *will* kill you!"—Sting.

Comment: "I will bend like a reed in the wind." - Paul Muad'Dib

Comment: “I will always love you.” — Dolly Parton

Comment: "You are such a smeghead."

Comment: You're the smeghead @MrLister!